# Give focus to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I'm working on keyboard accessibility. I have a flash object which sits inside a page, and to stop the focus getting trapped inside it, I've added tab listeners which talk through `ExternalInterface` to some JavaScript functions.

The JavaScript looks for the next available element with a `tabIndex` and calls `focus()` on it. So far so good. But if the plugin is the last tabbable item on the page (or first when reverse-tabbing), there is no element to switch to. Normally this would set focus to the browser window, so I'd like to keep that behaviour.

Hence my question: Is it possible to programatically give focus to the browser's chrome? Even better if I can mimic both forward *and* backward tabbing. Also I'd like to avoid adding extra tabbable components before/after the flash if possible, unless I can make them effectively invisible to both the mouse *and* keyboard.

Comment: try $(window).focus() yet?

Comment: "focusing the browser" is generally implemented by `window.focus();`

Comment: @Derek & jbabey: `$(window).focus()` does nothing

Comment: (at least, not in Google Chrome. Here's a fiddle for testing in other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/4NA5u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the focus to a dummy anchor with no text content, at the top of the document, seems to work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NA5u/1/.

Comment: As I said, I'd like to avoid adding extra tabbable components unless they can be made invisible to the keyboard; this way means that users need to press tab an extra time to get past. So I'll wait to see if anybody has another way.

Comment: Well nobody's had a better idea, so I'm going with this for now.

Comment: How about giving focus to any focuseable element, and immediately blurring it?

Comment: I suppose the final effect is removing focus from te flash movie.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this in my own search for a similar answer.  If you want to release the focus on the currently focused element, use document.activeElement;  If you want a fallback in the off chance its not supported, use focus on the parent element of the document.  This should support all known browsers, as far as I know:

```
var activeElement = document.activeElement;
if (activeElement) {
   activeElement.blur();
} else if (document.parentElement) {
   document.parentElement.focus();
} else {
   window.focus();
}
```