# Cannot give focus to Flash object with keyboard, but can focus with JavaScript

Tags: html, google-chrome, focus, embedded-flashplayer

This question is related to (but distinct from) my other question here: [Give focus to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842139/give-focus-to-browser)

I have an embedded flash object on my page, and I want it to be included in the tab cycle. I've set `tabindex` on it, which works in FireFox but in Google Chrome and Apple Safari focus still slips past.

Here's some simple test code:

```
<a href="#" tabindex=1>A</a>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width=550 height=400 id=movie_name tabindex=1>
    <param name=movie value="http://helpx.adobe.com/content/help/en/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player/_jcr_content/main-pars/flash_1/file.res/theFile.swf"/>
    <embed src="http://helpx.adobe.com/content/help/en/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player/_jcr_content/main-pars/flash_1/file.res/theFile.swf" name=movie_name type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" tabindex=1 />
</object>
<a href="#" tabindex=1>Z</a>
<button onclick="document.movie_name.focus()">Force focus into Flash</button>
```

(in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tcDGq/)

Everything has a `tabindex` of `1` (I also tried variations on `0`, `0,1,2`, etc), but it is impossible to focus the flash object with the keyboard. Clicking on it works, as does pressing the button, which triggers a simple bit of JavaScript. You can tell if it's focussed by mashing TAB; it will never give up focus via the keyboard so you'll never see anything highlight.

OK so I could hack together a fix which intercepts the TAB key and forces the focus in particular situations, but frankly that's a hideous solution. Is there some attribute I've missed here? I'm looking for a pure HTML fix if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug in WebKit, and therefore effects both Chrome and Safari (not FireFox, and I have no idea about Internet Explorer or Opera)

The relevant tracker is here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32292

Coincidentally, this was resolved a few days ago, so hopefully it will be in a public release soon. Since both Chrome and Safari manage to keep most users up-to-date, I don't think it's worth building a workaround in the meantime (but if anybody does have a nice workaround, please post it here!)